# Copy value of Pandas dataframe without conversion type using xlwings

Tags: python, pandas, xlwings

i have a problem while writing a pandas Dataframe into excel file using xlwings: i have a pandas dataframe that contains strings like '001' or '001234' but also numerical values as 3477 and when i use Range function of xlwings it converts this strings into numbers (so 1, 1234). With openpyxl i don't have this issue but it is too slow and i choose xlwings to do this work.

How I can force xlwings to not convert values?

Thanks

I try to setup any option of range function but it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.